# Angular 4 Material : use flex to wrap elements

Tags: angular, flexbox, responsive

I want to know how can I use flex to wrap my "product" elements like this example (angular js) :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwzRde

I'm using Angular 4 with Material.io and I saw flex for responsive.

But in this code, I can see this :

```
<div class='md-padding' layout="row" layout-wrap>
```

**layout="row"** and **layout-wrap** not exist in angular 4....

If you have an example, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those tags come from [angularjs-material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction). You can use normal [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) css to copy these properties:

```
myDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It does exist, but it's not more coupled to the Angular Material. You should add an extra package to use it.

It's the [Angular Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout). As you can see [here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation#containers), the properties that you've described are available on it too.